# Can default SQLServer instance name be empty string?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

Can **default** SQLServer instance name be empty string? Client argues he has ".\" as server\instance name. There are two kinds of instances: default and named instance and it seems logical that not named has no name. But MSDN says: default name is MSSQLSERVER.

Comment: The **service name** for the default instance is `MSSQLSERVER`, but the **instance name** is empty - so you connect to your **default instance** using `.`, or `(local)`, or `machinename` (without any further instance name) ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you stated, MSDN does state that the **default instance name** is `MSSQLSERVER`. It also states that an instance name **does not** need to be specified for a default instance to make a connection.

So to answer you question, the default instance name isn't empty, **but the reference to it can be**. Reference using the server / pc name.

More info related to default and named instances can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143744(v=sql.90).aspx).